# Как можно вернуть char через return?

Tags: objective-c, char

Идея такова: чтобы код данные со строки переворачивало наоборот, т.е. "divad"

```
char word [5] = "David";
char buf;
buf = word[3];
word[0] = word[4];
word[3] = buf;

buf = word[1];
word[1] = word[3];
word[3] = buf;

NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithCString: word encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это код переворачивает слово

```
NSString *myString = @"David";
NSMutableString *reversedString = [NSMutableString string];
NSInteger charIndex = [myString length];
while (charIndex > 0) {
  charIndex--;
  NSRange subStrRange = NSMakeRange(charIndex, 1);
  [reversedString appendString:[myString substringWithRange:subStrRange]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", reversedString);
```

Comment: Безмерно благодарен вам! Очень помогли! Спасибо большое! )